# =SUBSTITUTE is returning 0 when I try to remove dots

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column in Excel that has a lot of mac addresses, and they were copied like this:

```
0080.9fc9.a2ff
```

I wanted to remove the dots in it so I could copy and paste it to another place without having to do it mac by mac.

I tried this formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1;".";"")
```

It used to give me a circular reference error but I enabled iterative calculations and now it returns me a 0 instead of (following the first example)

```
00809fc9a2ff
```

As I wanted it to.

Edit: To help pinning down this issue I'm screenshotting exactly what is happening.

[image: The coordinates appear to be right]

Comment: Could you please edit the question and mention?: 1) What language edition you are using 2) What your Windows number format settings are.

Comment: Your formula should work, not sure why you are getting `circular reference error`.

Comment: About the format settings, they are values only.

Mac adresses were copied from another Excel that had alot of vlookups to search its values in another database, and I only wanted to extract its values.

I do believe my Excel is portuguese.

Comment: @zx8754 IT WAS, after I enabled iterative calculations the error disappeared but it still returns 0's (it was returning 0's with the error too)

Comment: @Atheisthotdog I am not questioning `if you have error` but `why would you with this simple formula`. You need to tell us more about your workbook.

Comment: I guess aparently my question is being downvoted, I wish to know the reason.

I have edited with every detail you are asking me for, and none of the answers solves the problem.

Even if the problem is noob or a big mistake on my part aren't the answers to blame for not pinning down the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your circular reference error. I just had to type your formula in the **C1** cell!

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1;".";"")
```

I think you just got the coordinates wrong.

---

To make it clear: you can't replace cell contents on the fly using a formula. You need to create a new cell to store the results. Otherwise, you'll need to use good old *search and replace* dialogue.

Comment: @Atheisthotdog - Right, that confirms the suspicion. You wrote a formula in C3 to replace stuff in C3.

Comment: Oh, =SUBSTITUTE is used in another cells to modify whatever I want in my desired cells, big dummy. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, because as soon as you save the formula, the original cell contents are gone forever. Glad we got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
=substitute(C1,".","")
```

ie, instead of semicolon `;` try to use comma `,`

[image]

Comment: I tried to edit the comment but I wasn't in time.

I read it somewhere that excel language varies its formulas, and in my case =SUBSTITUTE goes like this : 

=SUBSTITUTE(text; old_text; new text; [instance_num])

Comment: @Atheisthotdog:- Added the formula which works for me along with the screenshot

Comment: The benefits of pointless localization: in my Spanish edition I need to use `=SUSTITUIR(C1;".";"")` *sigh* As far as I know, `;` is the list separator in countries where `,` is used as decimal separator.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I feel you.